# regular expression to substitute forward slash with opening brackets

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I want to use regular expression to substitute forward slash with opening brackets, separated by a comma. For example, for

```
$str = "c/g/c/g/c/g/c/g";
```

the result should be

```
$str = "c),(g),(c),(g),(c),(g),(c),(g";
```

I wrote the following line but it does not work

```
$observed = ~ s///);(//;
```

Any advice how to solve it

Comment: Thanks for edit Hunter McMillen

Comment: `perl -E '$_= "c/g/c/g/c/g/c/g"; s{/}{),(}g; say'`

Comment: Why do you need regex for this? Would a replace on `/` with `),(` be sufficient enough?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney If you mean string replace, there is not a primitive in Perl for this. You would have to loop through each character and write out the update string to a different variable. Regular expressions are the correct solution for this in Perl (and probably other languages). Rather, the substitution operator is the Perl primitive for this type of operation.

Comment: Additionally, the binding operator is `=~`, not `= ~`. If you were using `warnings`, this would have produced the following warning: Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use a literal forward slash in a substitution that is delimted with forward slashes e.g. `s/../../g` you have to first *escape* the forward slash:

```
s/\//),(/; # Note: this only replaces a single occurrence
```

to replace all occurrences you can add the [`g(global)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) modifier:

```
s/\//),(/g;
```

You can also choose any other delimiter for the substitution expression, the following are all valid and equivalent:

```
s|/|),(|g;
s./.),(.g;
s#/#),(#g;
s{/}{),(}g;
```

It is also important to note that

```
$str = c/g/c/g/c/g/c/g.
```

is not a valid statement in Perl, all strings need to be enclosed in single or double quotes or the corresponding `q{}`, `qq{}` forms:

```
$str = 'c/g/c/g/c/g/c/g.';
```